# How to manually set data for kendoui treelist

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-treelist

I want to set the datasource for a kendoui treelist at the run time. Please check following [example](http://dojo.telerik.com/ApOCA/3). If I set the datasource at the design time, I am able to see the data in the control. But if I try to set the datasource at run time, I do not see the data in the control.

```
<div id="treeList"></div>
<script>
  var data = [ { name: "Jane Doe" }, { name: "John Doe" }];

    var dataSource = new kendo.data.TreeListDataSource({
      data: [ { name: "Jane Doe" }, { name: "John Doe" }]
    });
    $("#treeList").kendoTreeList({
      columns: [
          { field: "name" },
          { command: [{ name: "edit" }] }
      ],
      editable: true
      //,dataSource: dataSource
    });
  var grid = $("#treelist").data("kendoTreeList");
  grid.setDataSource( dataSource);
  grid.dataSource = dataSource;
   grid.dataSource.read();
  grid.dataSource.data(data);
</script>
```

Comment: @The_Black_Smurf: I have included the code. it is also available in fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the selector itself.  You logic was ok but for some reason, the object returned by `data("kendoTreeList")` was null.  I updated your code to chain the `data` after the `kendoTreeList` initialization.

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.TreeListDataSource({
  data: [ { name: "Jane Doe" }, { name: "John Doe" }]
});

var grid = $("#treeList").kendoTreeList({
  columns: [
      { field: "name" },
      { command: [{ name: "edit" }] }
  ],
  editable: true
}).data("kendoTreeList");

grid.setDataSource(dataSource);
```

It's a bit odd to say but I thought your code and my code would be equivalent. Obviously, it ain't but I can't figure out why.

Comment: Thanks. I think this line `.data("kendoTreeList");` right at the end made the difference.

Comment: Yes, it is... the main question here is why your line `var grid = $("#treelist").data("kendoTreeList");` didn't return the kendoTreeList object as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that you have the id to the DOM element set to "treeList".

```
var grid = $("#treelist").data("kendoTreeList");
```

As you can see here, you use all lowercase when setting the grid variable. That was your only problem. It should look like this:

```
var grid = $("#treeList").data("kendoTreeList");
```